# JSSOR: Only fits screen on page load, not on resize

Tags: jssor

The code I am using below only re-sizes the image slider upon page load, but doesn't re-size if the window size has changed, neither if the orientation of a mobile device changes.

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        var options = { $AutoPlay: true };
        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$('imageslider', options);


        function ScaleSlider() {
            var parentWidth = jssor_slider1.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
            if (parentWidth)
                jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(parentWidth);
            else
                window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
        }

        ScaleSlider();
        $(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
        $(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
        $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);

    });
</script>
```

Thanks in advance jssor

Comment: Highly recommended to download the latest version.

Comment: Hi, Yep it was the latest. I copied the code from an old stackoverflow post of yours :)

Answer (score 1):

For jquery version,

```
//responsive code begin
//you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizes
function ScaleSlider() {
    var bodyWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
    if (bodyWidth)
        jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(Math.min(bodyWidth, 1920));
    else
        window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
}
ScaleSlider();

$(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
$(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
$(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
//responsive code end
```

For no jQuery version,

```
//responsive code begin
//you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizes
function ScaleSlider() {
    var bodyWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
    if (bodyWidth)
        jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(Math.min(bodyWidth, 1920));
    else
        $Jssor$.$Delay(ScaleSlider, 30);
}

ScaleSlider();
$Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "load", ScaleSlider);

$Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "resize", $Jssor$.$WindowResizeFilter(window, ScaleSlider));
$Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
//responsive code end
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this to cover both re-size and orientation change.:

```
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {ScaleSlider();}, false);
window.addEventListener("resize", function() {ScaleSlider();}, false);
```